# Best way to UV unwrap a hole in the shape of a triangle?

Tags: uv, edges, faces

I need to unwrap this shape and I have problems with triangle holes in it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I unwrap this overlapping edges without stretching my whole UV map?

FBX file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4vQRwTIaF08QnA5NXhzai1jQkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Completely cut out the interior 'X' (add seams), and make it a '+' by rotating it. Perhaps better, split up each part of the 'X' into 'IIII' to make them even bigger.

Comment: @pycoder - resizing parts of a mesh's uv is only then a good idea if those parts use separate materials. Same material -> streching -> looks weird.

Comment: What do you mean by stretching? I said basically the same thing that you just said in your answer...more seams = less stretching!

Comment: @pycoder - I thought by "make them even bigger" you were refering to resizing UV islands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would cut out the whole "X section" and cut off two of the legs.

[image]

Comment: Why does your blender looking so beautiful? This soft shadows...

Comment: @Delinx - The fastest way to create the different colors for the UVs were three different colored materials. So I switched to Material Viewport (Blender Internal) and put a Hemi light into the scene.